# SSRS dropdown parameters won't re-populate

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dropdown

When I access any reports in reportserver, I am able to see the drop-down parameter being populated.  However, when I click on the drop-down arrow and click out of it AND then try to re-click on a drop-down parameter, it will no longer load.  These parameters aren't relying on any other parameters.  They get their values for a dataset.

Since, this is a problem with all the reports, do I need to modify the reportviewer.aspx?  Any idea how to fix this issue?

Screenshot (the parameter drop-down pretends to load and then gives up after a second):
[image]

Comment: In Parameter properties go to Advanced tab and check selection for when to refresh parameter. That may help.

Comment: I did try all three options:  Automatic, always, and never refresh parameter.  None of it would fix the issue I am facing.  Also, this just started happening recently.

Comment: @NonProgrammer, How is the parameter being populated? and what data should it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and found a couple of things that might help (depending on what browser and version you are using:

1. Try adding the report servers URL to the compatibility mode in IE
2. Try adding the report server URL to your list of trusted sites
3. If you are running the report server browser on the server itself, try turning off enhanced security mode
4. Lastly I have noticed that the report server control works very differently in different browsers - try it in Chrome as well as IE

Comment: It turned out to be a compatibility issue.  Still not understanding why it didn't work first few times when I played around with the compatibility settings.